# Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos (Angular, nodejs)

Tags: nodejs, angular

Hola Buenas tengo una duda que he podido notar que es muy recurrente, el problema es el título de la pregunta, aqui dejo mas detalle:

Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en http://localhost:3000/api/upload-image/6385fccc6eafeebadab3a61c. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito). Código de estado: (null).

Antes que nada quiero decir que tengo un formulario donde envió varios datos con éxito a mi servidor nodejs, pero cuando intento subir un archivo aparece el problema.

Quiero enviar mi imagen a la siguiente ruta.

```
const express = require('express');
const multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
const multipartMiddleware = multipart({uploadDir: '../uploads'})
const ProjectController = require('../src/controllers/project');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/upload-image/:id',multipartMiddleware, ProjectController.uploadImage);
```

Para eso hago uso del siguiente codigo:

metodo de envio de la imagen:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Global } from './global';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';

    uploadFile(File:Array<File>,id:string):Observable<any>{   
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this._http.post(this.url+'upload-image/'+id, File , {headers: headers})
    };
```

Y el evento para enviar la información es el siguiente:

```
onSubmit(form:any){  
    this._projectService.saveProject(this.project).subscribe( 
      (response)=>{
        var issetResponse:any;
        var id:string;
        issetResponse = response.project;
        id = response.project._id;

        //Aqui esta el metodo:
        this._uploadService.uploadFile(this.filesToUpload,id).subscribe();

        if(typeof issetResponse != undefined){
          this.status = true
        }else{
          this.status = false
        }    
        form.reset();
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.log(<any>error);
      });
      
  }
  fileChangeEvent(fileInput:any){
    this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files[0];
  }
```

Me gustaria que alguien me respondiera y esta pregunta no se quedara sin responder, también intente esto:

```
onSubmit(form: any) {
    var issetResponse:any;
    var id:string;
    id="";
    this._projectService.saveProject(this.project).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        issetResponse = response.project;
        id = response.project._id;
        console.log(id)
          if (typeof issetResponse != undefined) {
          this.status = true
        } else {
          this.status = false
        }
        form.reset();
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      });
      console.log(id)
      //Aqui esta el metodo: 
      this._uploadService.uploadFile(this.filesToUpload, id).subscribe();
      //Lo he cambiado de sitio pensando que talves el error fuera ese.
  }
  
  fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
    this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files[0];
  }
}
```

Sin embargo en este ultimo intento el problema viene de que (id) tienen un valor en el primer:

```
 console.log(id);
//la respuesta es: 6386083f339678846f422fd9, el id que necesito para pasar como parametro a mi ruta
```

Pero en el segundo:

```
console.log(id)
//Aparece como string empty
```

¿Hay alguna manera de poder sacar la información del

```
 id = response.project._id;
```

Fuera del bloque:

```
(response)=>{}
```

Por si alguien opina que el problema es mi cors: he intentado varias
configuraciónes del mismo y lo que yo no entiendo es que mi formulario si funciona, pero a la hora de enviar la imagen aparece ese error

aqui esta mi cors:

```
'use strict'
//Crear un servidor:
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const url = ['http://localhost:4200/'];

//Archivos de rutas:
const projectRoutes = require('./routes/project');

//Middlewares:
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Configurar cabeceras y cors:
app.use(cors({url}));

//Note que esta parte la he comentado porque tanto la configuración de 
//abajo como la de arriba producen el mismo resultado
// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
//     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
//     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
//     res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
//     next();
//     });
```

Comment: El problema de CORS no es de angular, es de tu backend. Si el backend no envía el encabezado que habilita el CORS, los navegadores cortarán la llamada por seguridad. Modifica el backend para desactivar la protección CORS.

Comment: Si lo deshabilito todo mi navegador es el que me lo bloquea.

Comment: no veo ningun parametro `url` en la documentacion de cors... porque no intentas mejor `cors({origin: true})`